# Learning classes but having an odd issue that I am sure is simple

Tags: python

So I am learning how to use classes and python and I am creating a simple program to perform arithmetic operations with rational numbers. I am creating a class called ArithmeticOperations. In this class I have a main function definition which prompts the user for the numerator and denominator of 2 rational numbers, then performs either the sum, difference, product, or quotient based on the choice of the user. The operations are performed in a separate function. Right now I have created the main function and the product function, but when I run it I get an error that says

> TypeError: product() takes exactly 5 arguments (6 given)

I am sure this is something simple but I am new to classes so i am having a bit of trouble debugging. Here is my current program:

```
class ArithmeticOperations:

    # Given numbers u0, v0, and side, design a pattern:
    def product(self,n1, d1, n2,d2):
        self.numerator = n1*n2;
        self.denominator = d1*d2;
        print n1,'/',d1,'*',n2,'/',d2,'=',self.numerator,'/',self.denominator; 


    def main(self):
        n1 = input('Enter the numerator of Fraction 1: ');
        d1 = input('Enter the denominator of Fraction 1: ');
        n2 = input('Enter the numerator of Fraction 2: ');
        d2 = input('Enter the denominator of Fraction 2: ');
        print '1: Add \n 2: Subtract\n 3: Multiply\n 4: Divide' ;
        question = input('Choose an operation: ');

        if question == 1:
            operation = self.sum(self,n1,d1,n2,d2);
        elif question == 2:
            operation = self.difference(self,n1,d1,n2,d2);
        elif question == 3:
            operation = self.product(self,n1,d1,n2,d2);
        elif question == 4:
            operation = self.quotient(self,n1,d1,n2,d2);
        else:
            print 'Invalid choice'


ao = ArithmeticOperations();
ao.main();
```

Comment: [Python Is Not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Comment: Augh, don't use semicolons in Python!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the method call, there is no need to explicitly specify `self`. Just call: `self.product(n1,d1,n2,d2);`, for the desired behavior.

Class methods will always have this extra `self` first argument, so that you can refer to the self inside the method body. Note also that unlike `this` in languages such as java (and many more), `self` is just a common good practice for the name of the first argument, but you could call it however you like and use it all the same.

Comment: Correspondingly, it is possible to override/disable polymorphism by calling `ArithemeticOperations.product(self, ...)`.